# Coloring cells in Excel with CMYK cell values

Tags: vba, colors, excel, cmyk

I'm looking for a way possibly using VBA to apply a cell's fill value by looking at specified fields in the same record. This would be a sample tab delimited Excel sheet:

```
BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT
SampleID    SAMPLE_NAME CMYK_C  CMYK_M  CMYK_Y  CMYK_K  LAB_L   LAB_A   LAB_B

BEGIN_DATA                              
1   1   100 0   0   60  34.16   -19.52  -27.46
2   2   100 100 0   60  22.02   6.27    -23.25
3   3   100 0   0   0   54.56   -31.12  -45.29
END_DATA
```

Fields 3-6 each contain the values for CMYK respectively. I'd like to apply a cell background fill to field 1 by parsing each record for the combined CMYK values as a starting point.

Conversion to RGB or HSL may need to be done initially unless there's a backdoor method to set CMYK values in the Excel/Windows color picker.

Comment: Can you use conditional formatting?  Not sure if that will help but it's an option to explore.

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure how I could input the CMYK values into a conditional rule or if it can look at four fields at once.

Comment: You'll need to convert your CMYK to RGB first. You can find the code to do that in Google. You can then use `rng.Interior.Color=[rgbvalue]` (where `rng` is a range reference). Note that if using excel 2003 or earlier, you may not get the exact color you set, since earlier versions use a fixed color palette, and map any colors not in that palette to the "closest" palette color.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: you're trying to convert between two different color schemes (one subtractive and the other additive) for which there doesn't exist a "perfect" conversion algorithm, so you may experience some unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give you the RGB from the CYMK in your data:

```
Function CYMK2RGB(c As Integer, y As Integer, m As Integer, k As Integer) As Long
Dim R As Integer
Dim G As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim colors As Integer

colors = 255 * (100 - k) / 100
R = colors * (100 - c) / 100
G = colors * (100 - m) / 100
B = colors * (100 - y) / 100

CYMK2RGB = RGB(R, G, B)
End Function
```

using `range("A1").Interior.Color=cymk2rgb(...)` will set the color - note it's not going to be an exact match, as CYMK is subtractive, and RGB is additive. this site: http://www.printernational.org/rgb-versus-cmyk.php has more details comparing the two.